# Handling a NSURLRequest with timeout when using delegate

Tags: iphone, timeout, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm using a NSMutableURLRequest to connect to a web site to get a JSON response.  I'm doing so by generating the request, and then using NSURLConnection with a delegate of self to handle the async connection.  I've implemented all the normal delegate methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

All works perfectly with getting data back, dealing with any errors that occur, etc.  However with the timeout on the NSURLRequest set to 10 seconds I don't seem to get called in those methods (I expected the didFailWithError to get called).  It just sits there forever and I have no notification that it timed out.

Reading the iPhone API docs I don't see any mention of what *should* happen when the timeout occurs, just that you can set the timeout value.  What should happen?  I didn't see any other delegate methods in the API that would help.  I don't have to manually check for timeouts, do I?  Are timeouts only for synchronous requests?

Comment: I concur Corey that I should get it in the didDailWithError method, but it's never getting called.  Both breakpoints and logs within that method show it never being called for a timeout.

Comment: For more context, incase it makes a difference, I am using the method talked about in the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332276/managing-multiple-asynchronous-nsurlconnection-connections to keep track of the connections I have outstanding.

Comment: I looks like this might have been a bug in the beta SDK of 3.0, because as soon as the final was release it worked as expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your timeout is received in this method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Comment: How can you test for timeout? That appears to be a generic error handler.

Comment: @devios1 set  url google.com for unavalable port, for example google.com:5555

Answer (score 4):

u will br receiving such type of iofo:

in did fail with

> error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 UserInfo=0xed4870
>   "timed out"

Comment: Note `NSURLErrorTimedOut = -1001`

Answer (score 3):

The timeout behaviour is a bit quirky, see [this thread](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/25282) on Apple’s developer forums.

Comment: That thread is great! Thanks! Note that thread gives you a reference to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html, which lists all the errors in the NSURLErrorDomain

Answer (score 2):

What I did was this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    if (error.code == -1001){
        [self showTimeoutAlert];//My method to show dialog with timeout message.
    } else {
        [self showInvalidURLAlert];//My method to show dialog with bad URL message.
    }
}
```

As said before -1001 is for timeout, in other tests I got -1003 (for bad URL or no connection avaliable).

I was aiming to treat timeout so anything else I treated as bad URL.

Answer (score 1):

Put some log statements in each method and check what they give. Whenever it times out, you definitely get a notification on the console about the timeout. I am getting that notification . Check your code and if you are still have problems, let us know.