# strange multiple files download - NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I encounter a problem by following your comment. I would like to download different file at same time with different delegate:

.h:

```
NSMutableData *fileData;
```

.m:

```
NSString *imgfile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxxx/01.jpg"];
NSURL *fileURL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:imgfile];

NSString *audiofile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxxx/01.mp3"];
NSURL *fileURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:audiofile];

NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL1 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0 ];
NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL2 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0 ];

NSArray *connections = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self ],
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request2 delegate:self ],
nil];

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    fileData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [fileData appendData:data];        
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Unable to fetch data");
}
```

ok, the download process works, but, the file size of jpg and mp3 are incorrect, the only correct thing is the total file size (jpg+mp3), please could you have a look on the code, what is missing?

Another question is, I put the file in a NSMutableArray, my question is, how to check which index of array is the correct file type (jpg and mp3)? because I need to save them to the device folder.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like both your connections write to the same `fileData` object and all your problems follow from that.
How to deal with multiple connections you can see [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332276/managing-multiple-asynchronous-nsurlconnection-connections) asked here on SO, there's also [nice blog post](http://blog.emmerinc.be/index.php/2009/03/02/custom-nsurlconnection-class-with-tag/) containing `NSURLConnection` subclass that addresses this issue.

Comment: hi Vladimir, thank you really much for the reply, I am almost there, but I encountered a problem, my app is UITableView based, I do not know how to implement :
@interface CustomURLConnection : NSURLConnection {
NSString *tag;
}

to my app:
@interface LessonSubViewController : UITableViewController{

}
@end
because there is a warning message says 'UITableViewController' may not respond to '-initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:'
and this causes the app crash, how can I solve it?

Comment: Implement it as a separate class inherited from NSURLConnection and then use its instance inside your LessonSubViewController methods.

Comment: THANK YOU REALLY MUCH!! I finally overcome this issue! and learned a lesson :)

Comment: hi Vladimir, I run into a sporadical problem, the data I received and saved to device was sometimes unable to be played(mp3) or displayed(jpg), I think there shall be something wrong at the data handling process because I didn't use "tag" to determine the actual data received, could you show some sample code to me? thanks a bunch

Comment: Sorry, its not clear what the problem is...Sample code is in the links I posted in answer. If you run your app on simulator you can browse to files you get and actually see if they are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am doing, I set a counter to identify the file type to save:

```
  - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSMutableData *dataForConnection = [self dataForConnection:(CustomURLConnection*)connection];
    [connection release];

   // Do something with the dataForConnection.

   downloadCount ++;

//  Copy Image Data to ur location using FileManager
//UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:fileData];
NSString *saveDir;
if (downloadCount ==1)
    saveDir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"001.jpg"];
if (downloadCount == 2)
    saveDir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"001.mp3"];

//NSLog(@"saveDir=%@",saveDir);
NSArray  * sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
NSString * filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@/%@", [sysPaths objectAtIndex: 0], saveDir];
NSLog(@"filePath=%@",filePath);

if([dataForConnection writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES])
    NSLog(@"DONE COPYING");
else
    NSLog(@"Write to device error");
//[fileData setLength:0];

if (downloadCount == 2)
{
    downloadCount = 0;
    play the MP3 and display the image file;
}
```

}

even I run the app on simulator, the file was download without error reported, but sometimes the file can not be opened, even I tried to open it from the folder, I was told the file was corrupted, I do not understand what was wrong, hope you do understand what I am saying.

Comment: SO works not like forum - if you have some extra information you should edit your initial question and post it there (or as a new question), but do not put it as an answer

Comment: sorry about that, because the comment has character limitation..
so do you read my question? I have been struggling on this issue for several days

Comment: It seems that you rely on fact that 1st connection finished will be jpg download, 2nd - mp3, but sometimes it is not so. Correct way to handle multiple connections must be the following: when you create connection you set a tag to it (say, kJPGConnection for downloading jpg, kMP3Connection - for mp3). When connection finished you check its tag and do corresponding action: if (connection.tag == kJPGConnection) - save as jpg.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I've solved the problem, the app runs very smooth!!