# iPhone program working on simulator but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I am using NSURLconnection to connect to a webservice and receive data. Since I connect to different webservices, I set the connection accessibilityLabel to a string describing the webservice.

In the delegate method

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection;
```

I check `connection.accessibilityLabel` and run the appropriate code.

This works perfectly in the simulator.

However, on the iPhone itself, `connection.accessibilityLabel` is always null.

Does anyone know why?

*(the connection still works properly and I get my data on the iPhone, I just dont know what to do with it since the accessibility label seems not to get set properly or is erased or something.)*

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: here is the code I use to make the connection and assign the label

```
// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
ConnectionDelegate *connDel = [[ConnectionDelegate alloc] init];
connDel.delegate = self;
conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:connDel];
conn.accessibilityLabel = label;

if (conn) {
    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere
    connDel.webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the iPhone Simulator is more "robust" than the iPhone itself. Critical functions are more likely to fail on the iPhone than on the iPhone Simulator.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I need your help. See [For standard UIKit controls and views, the value of it's accessibilityLabel property on real device can't be got, while the simulator can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671423/for-standard-uikit-controls-and-views-the-value-of-its-accessibilitylabel-prop)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your accessibilityLabel is only working on the simulator, but a more extendable approach can be found in the accepted answer for this question: [Managing multiple asynchronous NSURLConnection connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332276/managing-multiple-asynchronous-nsurlconnection-connections/332483#332483)

Basically you can create a mutable CFDictionary with your connection as a key and whatever you want as the value (in the linked answer he uses the receivedData object, but you could use whatever you wanted).

**So to adapt his solution for your situation you could do something like this:**

Before creating your requests:

```
connectionToInfoMapping =
    CFDictionaryCreateMutable(
        kCFAllocatorDefault,
        0,
        &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
        &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
```

After each connection is created:

```
CFDictionaryAddValue(
    connectionToInfoMapping,
    connection,
    [NSMutableDictionary
        dictionaryWithObject:@"someName"
        forKey:@"connectionName"]);
```

Then in your `connectionDidFinishLoading:` method:

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection
{
    NSMutableDictionary *connectionInfo = CFDictionaryGetValue(connectionToInfoMapping, connection);
    NSString *connectionName = (NSString *)[connectionInfo objectForKey:@"connectionName"];
    if ([connectionName isEqualToString:@"connectionA"]) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

The above can easily be extended to have multiple properties mapped by connection (Just add more keys and values to the NSMutableDictionary you add to the CFDictionary).

Comment: I edited my post to show my code, perhaps there is something wrong with my declarations.

As for your solution, does connectionToInfoMapping need to be a global variable? or how else can you access is both in the connectionDidFinishLoading: method and elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: `connectionToInfoMapping` should be a member of the calling class (`self` in your code above). This makes it "global" to the methods of `self`. So just add it to your .h file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the use of `accessibilityLabel`. Looking at the docs for it, it's intended to be used on UIKit controls to display the correct label on an accessibility element. Its behavior on `NSURLConnection` objects is undefined. I think you need to find another way of identifying the web service to your delegate.

Using an `NSDictionary` in `ConnectionDelegate` to associate the web service with active connections is as @theChrisKent recommended would work.

You could also create a subclass of NSURLConnection and add a `webServiceLabel` iVar & property to that.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up subclassing NSURL connection with additional properties.