# UIImageView Image from NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, nsurlconnection

I have a function that retrieves some images from a JSON feed using NSURLConnection. My `connectionDidFinishLoading` retrieves an array with all the data for that image (including the URL of the image).

What's the best way to display that image on a UIImageView? Even though the URL is being retrieved, I am pretty sure I would still have to display the image in a connection-friendly manner?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement Images must be display in connection friendly manner. Then you can go for `Image cacheing`  which requires image URLs. For your best understanding see this [link](http://www.ericd.net/2009/05/iphone-caching-images-in-memory.html#top) and [this link.](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/13315-image-caching-tutorial.html)

for asynchronous image downloading try with this  [link.](http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-uiimage-asynchronously/)

Comment: I am actually talking about asynchronous download and not caching. Any ideas?

Comment: check with this link images are downloaded asynchronously http://blog.sallarp.com/asynch-uiimage-revisited/

Comment: even check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332276/managing-multiple-asynchronous-nsurlconnection-connections