# Dealing with more than one NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, ios6, nsurlrequest

I have two `NSURLRequest` objects, connecting to a web service and invoking 2 different services.

The problem is that I have a random results, sometimes the first one is displayed first and sometimes the second `NSURLRequest` is the first.

```
NSString *urla=@"http://localhost:8080/stmanagement/management/retrieve_dataA/?match_link=";
NSString *uria = [urla stringByAppendingString:self.lien_match];
NSURL *urlla= [ NSURL URLWithString:uria];
NSURLRequest *requesta =[ NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlla];

NSString *urlb=@"http://localhost:8080/stmanagement/management/retrieve_dataB/?match_link=";
NSString *urib = [urlb stringByAppendingString:self.lien_match];
NSURL *urllb= [ NSURL URLWithString:urib];
NSURLRequest *requestb =[ NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urllb];

connectiona=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:requesta delegate:self];
connectionb=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:requestb delegate:self];

if (connectiona){
    webDataa=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

if (connectionb){
    webDatab=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}
```

Is that correct what I'm doing? Should I add a small break between the two `NSURLRequest`s?

Because at every view execution I have a random result. (I'm setting the results to two `UITableView` objects).

Comment: @glektrik your posted topic is since 2008! There is absolutely some things that has changed....

Comment: Is your problem that you're getting back results from both requests, possibly from the second one (connectionb) first, and you can't figure out which table view to put them in?

Comment: @androniennn things have changed indeed - BUT - correct answers usually remain valid.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't know that this should be considered a duplicate, as the candidate dup is about an arbitrary number of concurrent requests, and the solutions are all more complicated than is really needed if you just have **two**.

Comment: @Nate check the answers - there is one that specifically handles two.

Comment: @Till, yep.  Good catch.  I'd still say (as I missed that answer myself) that this two-connections-only question is worthy of leaving open.  I also don't think [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4786710/119114) has a particularly detailed response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your "problem" is that `self` is the connection delegate for **both** of your connections.  These type of connections are *asynchronous*, so there's no guarantee that A will complete before B. Your code should handle whatever order the web server returns data in.

I suppose you could make the two methods *synchronous* (don't start B until A completes), but I don't think there's really any **need** to do that.

The good news is that the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` callbacks pass you the `NSURLConnection` object, so you can use that to determine whether you're getting a response to A or B.  That information should tell you whether to put the data in the A or B web data object, and whether to update table view A or B, when the request completes.  For example:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // determine which request/connection this is for
    if (connection == connectiona) {
        [webDataa appendData: data];
    } else if (connection == connectionb) {
        [webDatab appendData: data];
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // determine which request/connection this is for
    if (connection == connectiona) {
        NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[webDataa length]); 
        // TODO(?): update the data source for UITableView (A) and call:
        [tableViewA reloadData];  
    } else if (connection == connectionb) {
        NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[webDatab length]);   
        // TODO(?): update the data source for UITableView (B) and call:
        [tableViewB reloadData];  
    }

    // release the connection* and webData* objects if not using ARC,
    //  otherwise probably just set them to nil
}
```

This solution requires you keeping `connectiona` and `connectionb` as persistent *ivars*, not local variables in the code you posted.  It looks like you're probably doing that, but since you don't show their declaration, I just wanted to be sure.

You should also [implement the other delegate callbacks, of course](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html), but the above two should give you a good example of the general solution.

Comment: You're the best! Thank you very very much! you've made my day :)). Two days with that problem :/. Thank youuu... :)))