# Differentiate between NSURLConnection objects in delegate

Tags: cocoa, nsurlconnection

I have two request starting one after the other. Starting request like this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                initWithRequest:request
                                delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
                      forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[connection start];
```

and another request starting like this.

```
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.apple.com"]];
NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
NSURLConnection *connection1 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self];
[connection1 release];
```

How can i differentiate between these two in delegate method?

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{}
```

Don't want to keep any extra class variable for this purpose.

Comment: Check if the `connection`argument in the callback method is equal to the `connection` or `connection1` variables in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Simple :

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
     if (connection == connection1)
     {
         //It's for connection1.
     }
     else if (connection == connection2)
     {
         //It's for connection2.
     }
}
```

You can go through this Beautiful SO Question : [Managing multiple asynchronous NSURLConnection connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332276/managing-multiple-asynchronous-nsurlconnection-connections)

Comment: In that case i have to keep two class variables Connection1 and Connection 2, as both connection may be working simultaneously. And I am trying to avoid these extra variables.

Comment: In that case, can I ask you why are you using this old approach ?

Comment: I found it easy to do. Will you please share the new approach?

Comment: The approach shared in link is the thing i needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

take your `NSURLConnection` objects in .h file and check in your delegate method as Markus has suggested.

or

Subclass your `NSURLConnection` and then you can add `tag` property to the connection class while creating, in you delegate methods check for appropriate tag. You can find [working tutorial here](http://www.isignmeout.com/multiple-nsurlconnections-viewcontroller/).